# Inject Jar and replace classes in running JVM

Tags: c++, jvm, java-native-interface, code-injection

I want to be able to replace and add some classes to an already running JVM. I read that I need to use `CreateRemoteThread`, but I don't completely get it. I read this post on how to do it ([Software RnD](http://xantorohara.blogspot.hu/2007/09/java-code-injection-via-winapis.html)), but I can't figure out what it does and why. Besides that, it only introduces new classes, but doesn't change existing ones. How can I do it with C++?

Comment: You need to create a dll containing the code you want (IE: Code to replace java classes in current JVM). When the dll loads, it creates a thread that loads your jar file. Then inject that dll into the JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need `CreateRemoteThread` - there is an official way to connect to remote JVM and replace loaded classes by using [Attach API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html).

1. You need a [Java Agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) that calls [Instrumentation.redefineClasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#redefineClasses-java.lang.instrument.ClassDefinition...-).

   ```
   public static void agentmain(String args, Instrumentation instr) throws Exception {
       Class oldClass = Class.forName("org.pkg.MyClass");
       Path newFile = Paths.get("/path/to/MyClass.class");
       byte[] newData = Files.readAllBytes(newFile);

       instr.redefineClasses(new ClassDefinition(oldClass, newData));
   }
   ```

   You'll have to add `MANIFEST.MF` with `Agent-Class` attribute and pack the agent into a jar file.

2. Then use Dynamic Attach to inject the agent jar into the running VM (with process ID = `pid`).

   ```
   import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;
   ...

       VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
       try {
           vm.loadAgent(agentJarPath, options);
       } finally {
           vm.detach();
       }
   ```

   A bit more details in [the article](http://www.javamagazine.mozaicreader.com/JanFeb2017/Default/31/0).

If you insist on using C/C++ instead of Java API, you may look at my [`jattach`](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) utility.

Comment: Hello @apangin, I stumbled upon your answer, and found your utility very interesting, as I'm trying to do something similar to VirtualMachine.attach(pid); without dependency to the JDK. So far no luck trying jattach load. I get '%1 is not a valid Win32 application' when trying to load my agent .jar. Any help?

Comment: @crankedrelic Please ask a separate question or submit an issue on the [project page](https://github.com/apangin/jattach).