# Read stdout of console app after IDE has crashed

Tags: windows, eclipse, stdout

Sometimes Eclipse dies and leaves a Java console program running. I want to access the console output after Eclipse died.

How can I do that?

I can see the console program in the Task Manager, so it's still running.

Comment: looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157989/inject-jar-and-replace-classes-in-running-jvm
I can connect to this JVM by Java API! Wow! But what's next???

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to [save the output to a file](http://code2care.org/2015/how-to-save-eclipse-console-logs-in-external-log-file/).

This is best for large logs, but will also work for your situation.

Comment: the question was about already running process from IDE which is died

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I misinterpreted the issue as not being able to read what had printed because the IDE crashed and the window was no longer available, not wanting to continue reading new output after the crash.

Comment: the original question contained some duplicates and language mistakes, so it was edited by community member, not sure if it's now better, as you trapped into misinterpretation..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was able to do it by writing custom Agent.jar with simple code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class Agent {
    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation) {

    }

    public static void agentmain(String agentArgs) {
        try {
            PrintStream psout =new PrintStream(new File("C:\\LOG\\out.txt"));
            PrintStream pserr =new PrintStream(new File("C:\\LOG\\err.txt"));
            System.setOut(psout);
            System.setErr(pserr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

with pre-created files.
I made it as a jar with Agent-Class string in MANIFEST.MF
then "injected" into running VM as simple as

```
public class TestAttachJVM {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception {
        VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach("<PID>");
        try { 
          // load agent into target VM
          String agent = "c:\\DIR\\agent.jar";
          vm.loadAgent(agent);
        } finally {    
          // detach
          vm.detach();
        }
    }
}
```

then I finished execution of this simple program, the out.txt and err.txt becomes locked.
unfortunately I can't see immediate output, as the program I am trying to hook makes any output every 1-4 hour. I'll check it out later.

Comment: seems it doesn't update the file. probably there is some security or over error

Comment: yes, it works. the issue was as I tried to load same agent class several times. this does not work for some reason. but changing agent class name, then repacking it in jar and then loading again fixes the problem.
it wasn't any security problem